Android resource compilation failed error when assambleRelease
I'm tring to generate an apk for my android app but im getting this errors like A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable > Android resource compilation failed ERROR: C:\Users\user\Desktop\salsaankara\SalsaAnkaraa\android\app\build\generated\res\createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets\drawable-mdpi\assets_cocukbale.png: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.
tried
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m, and opening each image in my assets folder and re save it as png but did not solve my problem.

assets_cocukbale.png maybe assets\cocukbale.png !

actually it should've been assets\cocuk-bale.png
